# Mistakes in custom pagination Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using `APIView` in my project and custom pagination also it is working but it shows same elements multiple time. Here I have tried so far.

**views.py**

```
class ProductByBrand(APIView):
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPaginationUpperBond

    @property
    def paginator(self):
        if not hasattr(self, '_paginator'):
            if self.pagination_class is None:
                self._paginator = None
            else:
                self._paginator = self.pagination_class()
        return self._paginator

    def paginate_queryset(self, queryset):
        if self.paginator is None:
            return None
        return self.paginator.paginate_queryset(queryset, self.request, view=self)

    def get_paginated_response(self, ctx):
        assert self.paginator is not None
        return self.paginator.get_paginated_response(ctx)

    def get(self, request, slug, brand, format='json'):

        pid = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
        data = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=pid)
        data_categories = []
        for category in data:
            data_categories += Category.objects.filter(parent_id=category.id)
        all_product = []
        for data_category in data_categories:
            all_product += Product.objects.filter(category_id=data_category.id, brand=brand)

        print(all_product)
        ctx = []
        for product in all_product:
            str = settings.MEDIA_URL + product.image.name
            ctx.append({
                'id': product.id,
                'name': product.name,
                'slug': product.slug,
                'brand': product.brand_id,
                'image': str,
                'price': product.price,
                'rating': product.rating,
                'discount': product.discount
            })
        queryset = Product.objects.all()
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            return self.get_paginated_response(ctx)
```

to be more precise I select brand in category section to filter the products related to that category. For example:
I have two product

[image]

as it can be seen from `electronics` category it has two products related to brand which id is **3**. In this case I have only two products not four. But it gives me 4 same product instead of 2 as you can see from the picture above. How can I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see more of what your data looks like, but you're probably getting duplicates because of the two `for` loops. Those can be direct ORM queries something like this:

```
def get(self, request, slug, brand, format='json'):

    pid = Category.objects.get(slug=slug)
    data = Category.objects.filter(parent_id=pid)

    data_categories = Category.objects.filter(parent__in=data)
    all_product = Product.objects.filter(category__in=data_categories, brand=brand)
    print(all_product)
    ctx = []
    for product in all_product:
    [...]
```